# JPG to PDF conversion Cordova plugin

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, jspdf

I am using ionic framework, I want to pick a image file from galley and want to convert it to PDF and want to save it on filesystem on phone.
Is there any javascript or cordova plugin is available to perform this task.

I found [jsPDF](https://parall.ax/products/jspdf) can be use to convert image to pdf but, does it really work on mobile?

Comment: by playing with jsPDF a bit I think it should work in mobile.

Comment: @ArpitVasani can I save PDF in filesystem

Comment: @Anil8753 I suggest you to have a look at this link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28669480/generating-pdf-file-with-ionic-framework. All you need to do is to convety your JPG file to base64 image URI and feed into the plugin to get PDF out of it. Hope it helps.

Comment: @Anil8753 Yes you can. once PDF is ready by jsPDF then use 
[this plugin](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file/index.html#file-system-layouts) to save it in device.

Answer (score 1):

I hope I'm not that late!

Aside from [jSPDF](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF), following packages are needed:

- cordova-plugin-file
- cordova-plugin-file-opener2

And install the corresponding ionic-package:

```
bower install ngCordova
```

Please note that, there are several possible solution as to how to save a pdf file in your filesystem. I had to move the pdf-file to a certain directory in order to open it. Nevertheless this solution works on all android phones I've tested so far and you can create all pdfs you like.

iOS: You might modify the storage-directory so that it works on iOS-Version as well.

Index.html:

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
... include jsPDF
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.2/jspdf.debug.js"></script>

....
some html
....

... include ngCordova
<script src="lib/ngCordova/dist/ng-cordova.js"></script>

.... the core-library
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
....
</head>
```

View.html:

```
<ion-view view-title="Dashboard">
  <ion-content class="padding">
    <p on-tap="savePDF()">Create PDF</p>
    <p on-tap="openPDF()">Open PDF</p>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

App-JS:

```
// to not forget to include ngCordova in order to use $cordovaFile in your controller
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers', 'starter.services','ngCordova'])
...
...
```

Controller-JS:

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', []).controller('DashCtrl', function($scope,$cordovaFile) {

  $scope.pdfFilename = "test.pdf";

  $scope.makePDF = function(){
    var imgData = "your base64 image-data";

    var doc = new jsPDF();

    doc.setFontSize(40);
    doc.text(35, 25, "Octonyan loves jsPDF");
    doc.addImage(imgData, 'JPEG', 15, 40, 180, 180);
    return doc.output('blob');
  };

  $scope.getDirectoryInfo = function(){
    return {
      storage: cordova.file.externalRootDirectory, // for android, you may have to use another directory
      pdfDir: cordova.file.externalRootDirectory+"pdfs/"
    }
  };

  $scope.savePDF = function(){
    var dirs = $scope.getDirectoryInfo();
    var storageDir = dirs.storage;

    // create directory on the first place if it has not been created so far
    $cordovaFile.createDir(storageDir, "pdfs", false);

    var pdfBlob = $scope.makePDF();
    // create empty pdf-file(in the root-dir)
    $cordovaFile.createFile(storageDir, $scope.pdfFilename, true).then(function(success) {
      // write pdf-file(in the root dir)
      $cordovaFile.writeExistingFile(storageDir, $scope.pdfFilename, pdfBlob, true).then(function (success) {
        var fullTmpPath = storageDir + $scope.pdfFilename;
        window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(fullTmpPath, function (fileEntry) {
          // get destination-directory to put your pdf into
          window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(dirs.pdfDir, function (dirEntry) {
            // move written pdf to the destination-directory
            fileEntry.moveTo(dirEntry, $scope.pdfFilename, function (newFileEntry) {
              alert($scope.pdfFilename+' is finish! Now you can open it');
            });
          });
        });
      }, function (error) {
        console.log('there was some error while writting file: ',error);
      });
    });

  };

  $scope.openPDF =function(){
    var dirs = $scope.getDirectoryInfo();
    cordova.plugins.fileOpener2.open(dirs.pdfDir+$scope.pdfFilename,'application/pdf',function(){
      console.log('success');
    });
  };

});
```

Hope this helps despite the fact that your question has been put some time ago.